# JAXRS Server check status

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I have created a `JAXRS SERVER` for some web services. The server is working just fine, but I need to add a new feature so that I can check the server status at any time. So if the server is up I should return a message like `running`,and if is down a message like `down`.

My implementation so far:

```
public class Server
{

   public static void main( final String[] args )
   {

      final JAXRSServerFactoryBean serverFactory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();

      final SubscriptionService subscriptionService =
            new SubscriptionService( SubscriptionRepo.getRepo() );
      final SystemService systemservice = new SystemService();

      serverFactory.setResourceProvider(new SingletonResourceProvider(subscriptionService));
      serverFactory.setResourceProvider(new SingletonResourceProvider(systemservice));

      serverFactory.setAddress( "http://localhost:8888" );

      serverFactory.setProvider( JacksonJsonProvider.class );
      serverFactory.create();
   }
}
```

I have also created a service class where I want to get the status:

```
public class SystemService
{

   @GET
   @Path("/systemstatus")
   public Response getSystemStatus()
   {
      return Response.status( Status.OK.getStatusCode() );
   }
}
```

I really have no idea how can I return a status if the system is running or not. 
Can anyone help me with some ideas on how to check the server status?

Comment: Well, if the server is down you'll probably receive a 404 HTTP response. Thus, you can check the Response Code after an HTTP request: if you get a 200 (or a 2xx) the server is running, if you get a 404 (or a 4xx or 5xx), the server is down.

Comment: That's not so relevant..I can get a 404 response also when I request a URI that doesn't exist. But the server is still up and running...

Comment: Well, if you own your server, a 404 will surely mean that the server is down, since your URI won't change, and you'll check the response only for that URI... or am I missing something? :)

Comment: I own the server, but the requests come from outside. I would like a way to check at any time if the server is up or not. I was thinking about having a flag set on true when you create the server, and when the server is stopped change the value of the flag. But I don't know how to do this

Comment: The fact is, if the server is down it will never respond, so it won't tell to any client wether your flag is set to true or false. The only thing that comes into my mind is creating an independent client application, possibly on another machine, that keeps sending requests to your web server to check if it's down or not. In case it's down, that application could send a notice to all your possible clients (e.g. by sending them an email).

Answer (score 0):

Your quest kind of collapses on itself when you consider that you're trying to get a response from a web service, that's deployed on a non-responsive web server. How exactly do you envisage your web service getting the word out (by way of a coherent HTTP status, no less), that it's not reachable? How are you even going to get to it in the first place? When the container is down, *your service is not in a position to return any meaningful message to the client*

Stick to time-tested exception handling in the various flavours of the connection-related [`SocketException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html) and possibly the [`HttpRetryException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpRetryException.html), in some cases. That's all you're going to get when your server is not up: some variety of `SocketException`. Your REST service has no power here.